# Opening an image in a new tab without downloading it (Just show image-only)

Tags: image, tabs, download, popup, window

I'm working for a company and my work is to add content on a e-learning environment. It's not really my task but the instructions I have to add are big screenshots, we're working with Moodle and the customization doesn't go that deep. Ive made 3 (working) codes with scripts I found to enlarge an image in the same window but that doesnt seem possible (because of the interface of moodle), so it has te be done with making a new window with the image at full size. A new problem occurred, the image keeps getting downloaded (and there are sometimes some random outlook openings), so I have to force the image to be shown in a new tab and not being downloaded.
This is what I tried

```
<div class='item'>
<a href="url" target="_top">
<img width="954" height="243" style="cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;" src="url" />
</a><div class='thumb' attribute='onclick'>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Btw, this is the first time i'm really working with html, but I've always been handy with computers. And it's not possible to add files in the webserver like lightbox, it has to be done with an script or just a plain html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Setting target to _blank will open image in new window

```
 <div class='item'>
 <a href="url" target="_blank">
 <img width="954" height="243" style="cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;" src="url" />
 </a><div class='thumb' attribute='onclick'>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set the target attribute in a link tag to "_blank" it should open in a new tab

```
<a href="url" target="_blank">...</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! Not sure if that was the problem, I forgot to add target in my question, but it's solved